# How can I open a pop-up window by clicking on the button from the contextMenu?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking way **Chrome Extension** how can I open a pop-up window by clicking on the button from the **contextMenu** of the browser?
**Example**: I click and opened extension pop-up window

[image] [image]

(*Sorry for the rude example.*)

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: How about modal or dialog box? 
I want make extension: selected text on webpage and call something (modal, dialog) with data, not move from page.

Comment: Sure, you can open a new window via chrome.windows.create (from your background script), or add an iframe in the web page pointing to your extension page whitelisted in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/manifest/web_accessible_resources) (from your content script).